# ¿"Cabalgata" pero en camello?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, animales

En español existe [*cabalgata*](https://dle.rae.es/cabalgata) para referirse a la acción de [*montar a caballo*](https://dle.rae.es/cabalgar).

¿Existe un término equivalente para cuando se hace en camello?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no existe algo específico y el sustantivo que se emplea para una caravana o marcha  `unión de jinetes` que monten camellos es también ***cabalgata***

Aquí puede leerse en la página [153 de "Alma criolla"](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=f4EzAQAAIAAJ&q=%22cabalgata+de+camellos%22&dq=%22cabalgata+de+camellos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj58anW5pvuAhU7GLkGHaqDCScQ6AEwAnoECAAQAg) (1909, novela de Francisco Jiménez Arráiz) el término aplicado a los dromedarios

> *(..) con las cuales fabricaba el viento una `cabalgata de camellos` blancos entrando pensativos en una ciudad desierta , cuyas torres y palmeras se empinasen sobre el resplandor de un incendio; (..*.)

Supongo que esto es una deriva lógica, una generalización del término [cabalgar](https://dle.rae.es/cabalgar?m=form) que tiene entre sus acepciones también el `poner una cosa sobre otra`, y por lo tanto puede aplicarse al ir a lomos de otras especies (con lo que excede a la especie principal que los humanos aprendieron a montar para transportarse)

Comment: Como una nota curiosa, en El Salvador se usa bastante el verbo "camellar", no para andar a camello, sino para trabajar arduamente o para caminar mucho (como los camellos :)

Comment: En Argentina, para caminar mucho a veces decimos "caminar como un beduino" (el jinete de los camellos).

Comment: Y si preguntas a un niño español qué es la “cabalgata”, te dirá que es la llegada de los reyes magos el día 5 de enero a lomos de sus camellos.

Comment: @aerobiomat  [off topic] Según la tradición en México, los Reyes Magos precisamente cabalgan un camello, un elefante y un caballo,pero quizá en España todos son Camellos

Comment: Parece que en México hay más biodiversidad :-). Y viene bien el dato porque también se puede cabalgar en elefante.